# Statistic Power calculation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I recently started to study hypothesis testing. I find out that 
"The power of a hypothesis test is the probability that the decision rule leads to the right conclusion when the null is false."

so based on my search, I find that in order to calculate the probability of detection or power we should use the below formula

$$\int_ξ^\infty p(x|H1) \,dx$$

here x is our sample or data and H1 is alternative hypothesis and is threshold level

but when I tried to read another subject, such as proof of Neyman Pearson Lemma theorem, I saw that the power or power function defined as
$$E_\Theta[φ(X)]$$ 
( φ is Test statistic and Theta is model's Parameters (Theta1 is parameter value when alternative hypothesis is true and Theta0 is model parameter when null hypothesis is the correct one)).

which I find confusing, so my question is: 
Are these two mentioned formulas the same?
and
How we calculate power based on which formula?

Comment: Power is different from power function. The expression for power function is $E_{\theta}(\varphi(X))$ where $\theta$ is some unknown quantity in the probability model and $\varphi$ is the test function for testing some hypothesis about $\theta$.

Comment: thank for your answer, can you please tell me what is power function and how it different from hypothesis 's power?

Comment: Please consult your notes/textbook for definitions. Power of the test $\varphi$ is calculated as $E_{\theta_1}[\varphi(X)]$ where $\theta_1$ is the value of $\theta$ in the alternative hypothesis. In other words, it is the power function evaluated at $\theta=\theta_1$ (assuming you are testing a simple null vs a simple alternative).

Comment: thank again, as I said in my main question I search and read a lot of sources, but I find these 2 formula confusing, and again I don't understand. based on your last answer Eθ1[φ(X)]  is power function when θ=θ1 i.e. power and the power also could be calculated from formula # 1. but these 2 fourma arent equal mathematically so how could they indicate to the same thing?

Comment: and what does Eθ0[φ(X)] mean? I mean it could not be defined the power of test? because we use the null hypothesis, not alternative one?

Comment: You did not read my comments.

Comment: actually I read your comment, from your response it seems that I didn't get it, so could you please answer it differently

Answer (score 0):

You show formulas without definitions of symbols, and with no
work of your own. So it is difficult to assess what you
understand and what you don't. Here is a discussion of a very simple
situation in which everything can be calculated using binomial distributions. I hope it is helpful.

Suppose you flip a coin $n=50$ times, suspecting it may be
biased towards Tails. You will test $H_0: p = .5$ against 
$H_a: p \le .5,$ rejecting $H_0$ if the number $X$ of Heads
in 50 independent tosses is less than or equal to critical
value $c = 18,$

Because $P(X \le c|H_0) = P(X \le c|p=.5) = 0.0325$ this is a test at level 3..25%. That is, the probability of Type I Error is $ 0.0325.$ Because of the discreteness, it is not possible to
do a (nonrandomized) test at exactly the 5% level of significance.
[Computation in R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF.]

```
pbinom(18, 50, .5)
[1] 0.03245432
```

To find the power against the specific alternative $p_a = .25,$ you need
to find $P(X \le c|p=.25) = 0.9713.$  That is, the probability of 
Type II error is 1 - 0.9713 = 0.0287.

```
pbinom(18, 50, .25)
[1] 0.9712668
```

A power curve for this test would plot the probability of rejection
against the specific alternative values $p_a$ of interest.
A plot of this power curve is shown below the R code used to make it.
The dotted red line shows power at $p_a = .25,$ computed just above.

[To make a power curve with a calculator, you could plot half a
dozen carefully chosen points $p_a$ (instead of 401), connecting them with a hand-drawn curve.]

```
p.a = seq(.5, .1, by=-.001)
pwr = pbinom(18, 50, p.a)
plot(p.a, pwr, type="l", ylim=0:1, lwd=2)
 abline(h = 0:1, col="green2")
 abline(v = c(.5,.1), col="green2")
 abline(v = .25, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to edit my question and i add the definition of the symbol

Comment: Editing difficulties notwithstanding, do you understand the ideas of 'power' and 'power function'?